# Reloading JavaScript within the HTML DOM

Tags: dom, reload, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Is there a way to reload JavaScript within a DIV block without doing a page refresh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the javascript, say in a string

```
 var script = "...";
```

by calling the eval function

```
 eval(script);
```

Comment: really cool! it works... the only issue is it sometimes doesn't parse out spaces correctly at least in firefox.

Comment: You might start another question and paste the string of code you are using with eval() and what the result is.